# Box2D Walls - same code: the left one works, the right one doesn't

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, box2d

I'm making a simple Box2D game ( http://iwanttobeacircle.com ), where you start off as a triangle and bounce off bigger shapes to gain sides.

I'm having a bizarre bug with my walls... both are created from the same class, yet the left one works and the right doesn't. If I only add the right one, then it works, but for some reason adding them both seems to be causing a problem somewhere.

The WallSegment class is below:

```
    package com.carmstrong.iwanttobeacircle {

 import flash.display.DisplayObjectContainer;
 import flash.display.Sprite;
 import flash.display.Shape;
 import Box2D.Collision.Shapes.*;
 import Box2D.Dynamics.*;
 import Box2D.Common.Math.b2Vec2;

 import com.carmstrong.iwanttobeacircle.Config;

 public class WallSegment extends Actor {

  private var _shape:Sprite;
  private var _shapeBody:b2Body;
  private var _colour:uint = 0x666666;

  private var prevEdge:int;
  private var thisEdge:int;
  private var side:Number;

  private var name:String;

  private var _pathWidth:int;
  private var _parent:DisplayObjectContainer;

  public function WallSegment(Width:int, Position:String, Parent:DisplayObjectContainer) {
   name = "Wall";
   _pathWidth = Width;
   _parent = Parent;

   if(Position == "left") {
    side = 1;
    prevEdge = (Config.WIDTH - Config.PREV_WIDTH)/2;
    thisEdge = (Config.WIDTH-_pathWidth)/2;
   } else {
    side = -1;
    prevEdge = Config.WIDTH-(Config.WIDTH - Config.PREV_WIDTH)/2;
    thisEdge = Config.WIDTH-(Config.WIDTH-_pathWidth)/2;
   }// check if its left or right wall


   //Create the costume
   drawShape();
   drawBody();

   super(_shapeBody, _shape);
  }//DynamicWall

  private function drawShape():void {
   //Draw visual
   _shape = new Sprite();

   var left:Sprite = new Sprite();

   left.graphics.beginFill(_colour, 0.5);
   left.graphics.moveTo(prevEdge, Config.HEIGHT/2);
   left.graphics.lineTo(prevEdge-Config.WIDTH*side, Config.HEIGHT/2);
   left.graphics.lineTo(thisEdge-Config.WIDTH*side, -Config.HEIGHT/2);
   left.graphics.lineTo(thisEdge, -Config.HEIGHT/2);
   left.graphics.endFill();
   _shape.addChild(left);

   _parent.addChild(_shape);
  }//drawShape

  private function drawBody():void {
   //Create the shape definition
   var shapeDef:b2PolygonDef = new b2PolygonDef();
   shapeDef.vertexCount = 4;
   b2Vec2(shapeDef.vertices[0]).Set(prevEdge/Config.RATIO, Config.HEIGHT/2/Config.RATIO);
   b2Vec2(shapeDef.vertices[1]).Set((prevEdge-Config.WIDTH*side)/Config.RATIO, Config.HEIGHT/2/Config.RATIO);
   b2Vec2(shapeDef.vertices[2]).Set((thisEdge-Config.WIDTH*side)/Config.RATIO, -Config.HEIGHT/2/Config.RATIO);
   b2Vec2(shapeDef.vertices[3]).Set(thisEdge/Config.RATIO, -Config.HEIGHT/2/Config.RATIO);
   shapeDef.density = 0;
   shapeDef.friction = 10;
   shapeDef.restitution = 0.45;

   //Create the body definition (specify location here)
   var shapeBodyDef:b2BodyDef = new b2BodyDef();
   shapeBodyDef.position.Set(0, -Config.HEIGHT*(Config.CURRENT_SEGMENT+1)/Config.RATIO);

   //Create the body
   _shapeBody = Config.world.CreateBody(shapeBodyDef);

   //Create the shape
   _shapeBody.CreateShape(shapeDef);

  }//drawBody

 }//class

    }//package
```

To keep the level dynamic, the walls are drawn just ahead of the player object each time in the main class, using the following code:

```
private function addWall(Width:int) {      
   Config.CURRENT_SEGMENT++;

   //addWalls
   var leftWall:WallSegment = new WallSegment(Width, "left",camera);
   var rightWall:WallSegment = new WallSegment(Width, "right",camera);

   Config.PREV_WIDTH = Width;
  }//addWall
```

I'm getting this error:

> TypeError: Error #1010: A term is
>   undefined and has no properties.  at
>   com.carmstrong.iwanttobeacircle::GameContactListener/Add()
>    at
>   Box2D.Dynamics.Contacts::b2CircleContact/Evaluate()
>    at
>   Box2D.Dynamics.Contacts::b2Contact/Update()
>    at
>   Box2D.Dynamics::b2ContactManager/Collide()
>    at Box2D.Dynamics::b2World/Step()  at
>   com.carmstrong.iwanttobeacircle::IWantToBeACircle/everyFrame()

Which refers to the GameContactListener class, shown below (the add function is at the bottom):

```
    package com.carmstrong.iwanttobeacircle {

 import Box2D.Collision.b2ContactPoint;
 import Box2D.Dynamics.b2ContactListener;

 public class GameContactListener extends b2ContactListener {

  public function GameContactListener() {

  }//GameContactListener  

  override public function Add(point:b2ContactPoint):void {

   if (point.shape1.GetBody().GetUserData() is ShapeActor && point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData() is ShapeActor) {
    //trace("Two shapes collided: Shape 1 has "+ point.shape1.GetBody().GetUserData().sides + " sides and Shape 2 has " + point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().sides + " sides");

    if (point.shape1.GetBody().GetUserData().sides > point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().sides) {
     //remove side from shape 1 and add side to shape 2
     point.shape1.GetBody().GetUserData().sides--;
     point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().sides++;
     //point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().updateColour;
    } else if (point.shape1.GetBody().GetUserData().sides < point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().sides) {
     //remove side from shape 2 and add side to shape 1
     point.shape1.GetBody().GetUserData().sides++;
     point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().sides--;
     //point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().updateColour;
    }// add side to smaller shape and take away from larger shape

    if(point.shape1.GetBody().GetUserData().name == "player" || point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().name == "player") {


     if(point.shape1.GetBody().GetUserData().name == "player" && point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().sides <= point.shape1.GetBody().GetUserData().sides) {
      Config.FULFILLMENT++;
      Config.SOUNDS[3+Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)][1].play();
      trace(Config.FULFILLMENT);
     } else if (point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().name == "player" && point.shape1.GetBody().GetUserData().sides <= point.shape2.GetBody().GetUserData().sides) {
      Config.FULFILLMENT++;
      Config.SOUNDS[Math.ceil(Math.random()*5)][1].play();
      trace(Config.FULFILLMENT);
     } else {
      Config.SOUNDS[Math.ceil(Math.random()*3)][1].play();
      Config.FULFILLMENT = int(Config.FULFILLMENT - 5);
      trace(Config.FULFILLMENT);
     }//if other shape is less than or equal to player
    }//if one of the shapes is player
   }// if both collider objects are shapes

   super.Add(point);

  }// override Add

 }//class 

    }//package
```

I would appreciate any thoughts or ideas. Also, this is my first go at Box2D so would appreciate any tips on how to make my code more efficient.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might help to narrow down which data is null in the Add() method--there are a lot of options: point, point.shape1, point.shape1.GetBody(), etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're asking two questions here

1. Why is the left and right wall collision detection not working?
2. Why is there an error on the GameContactListener/Add() method?

It looks like they may have the same root problem. I'm seeing you're adding the wall segments as children of the "camera" (had to trace where this add was happening... you pass a reference of "camera" into the constructor of the object.)

```
i.e.    var leftWall:WallSegment = new WallSegment(Width, "left",camera);
```

Within there, you add the leftWall as a child of that object. But I'm not sure what "camera" is... Is this part of your game world object?

Also, what are your trace statements for point.shape1 and point.shape2? 
What 2 objects are colliding?